# A trendy thing to do here is where/that young people do not wear glasses. - which one to use?

Tags: word-usage, usage

**Example 1**

> A trendy thing to do here is **that** young people do not wear glasses.

> A trendy thing to do here is **where** young people do not wear glasses.

**Example 2**

> The phenomenon is **that** they consume the food and spit it out to eat it later.

> The phenomenon is **where** they consume the food and spit it out to eat it later.

**Example 3**

> The scenario was **that** he hit me first and I fought back.

> The scenario was **where** he hit me first and I fought back.

Are all the sentences correct?

What is the difference?

Comment: I wouldn't use _where_ for any of them.  As to the first one, **not** wearing glasses is not 'doing something'. _There is a trend here for young people not to wear glasses._

Comment: *A trendy thing **for young people** to do here is that **they** do not wear glasses.* But even though all the examples above are "awkward / invalid", the ***where*** versions are by far the worst.